# Is there a difference between caching IEnumerable or IList in HttpRuntime cache?

Tags: c#, list, caching, ienumerable, httpruntime.cache

Assuming the following piece of code that caches two collections of objects `MyObject`: one collection is of type `IEnumerable<MyObject>` and the other one is of type `List<MyObject>`.  The code retrieves the values from the cache and then accesses the collection:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CacheManager.CacheSomething();
    }

    public class MyService
    {
        private IEnumerable<AnObject> AnObjects
        {
            get
            {
                return new[]
                {
                    new AnObject {MyString1 = "one", MyString2 = "two"},
                    new AnObject {MyString1 = "three", MyString2 = "four"}
                };
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<AnObject> GetEnumerable()
        {
            return AnObjects;
        }

        public List<AnObject> GetList()
        {
            // Run it out to a list
            return AnObjects.ToList();
        }
    }

    public static class CacheManager
    {
        public static void CacheSomething()
        {
            // Get service
            var service = new MyService();

            // Get the values as List and Enumerable
            var list = service.GetList();
            var enumerable = service.GetEnumerable();

            // Putting them in a cache
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("list", list);
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("enumerable", enumerable);

            // Get the values
            var retrievedList = HttpRuntime.Cache["list"] as List<AnObject>;
            var retrievedEnumerable = HttpRuntime.Cache["enumerable"] as IEnumerable<AnObject>;

            // Access both
            var res1 = retrievedList.ToList();
            var res2 = retrievedEnumerable.ToList();               
        }
    }

    public class AnObject
    {
        public string MyString1 { get; set; }
        public string MyString2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is there a difference in terms of the amount of memory required to store these objects based on the collection types?

The reason that I ask is that when we have been profiling our applications and we've noticed that when we look at the dependency tree, the `IEnumerable` has the Service associated with it.  Does that mean that it caches the service too?

Can anyone shed some light as to whether this is a cause for concern?  Is it a problem to store an `IEnumerable` in the cache?  Should we prefer caching `List`s over `IEnumerable`s?

Comment: If you've gone through the process of writing up all this, why not go one step further and use a benchmark tool to see how both perform and what they allocate?

Comment: I've just spent the best part of my day investigating this and I still don't have a concrete answer.  Getting proof of this is harder that you might think.

Answer (score 3):

And `IEnumerable` is **not** data. It is a *promise* that you will *receive* data when you ask. Some data might implement it (arrays, lists) but sometimes, it's not materialized data but instead a query to a database.

"Caching" your `IEnumerable` means you cache the knowledge where to *get* data. That's not what you want. You want to cache *the data itself*.

Always materialize your `IEnumerable`s before caching the result (for example with ToList or ToArray). Otherwise, you might end up with a cache that just holds a procedure that is called to get you the data.

---

The fact that the `IEnumerable` in your example still holds a reference to the service is exactly that: it does not hold *data*, it holds the reference to the service *and will call it again* when you use it. So the exact opposite of what you want from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Difference in amount of memory? No.

Why? `IEnumerable` is not a type; it's an interface. That means that anything stored in an `IEnumerable` is actually some other type that implements `IEnumerable` (like `List`, for example).

`IEnumerable` only forces implementation of methods to read the list. It's not appropriate for modifying the collection. That's why you would want to cast it to the actual type (like `List`), so you can use methods like `Add`.

Comment: Thanks.  So in terms of memory usage, if as @nvoigt says, storing a promise of data when asked, if it doesnt store the data itself then I thought it might be different in terms of the memory footprint? (A pointer to a promise of data is different to storing the actual materialised data in the cache?)  Thanks for your time and knowledge.